# Navigate to another view from Appdelegate through a UIButton

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, uistoryboardsegue

I have the following issue. I have made a UIButton in my Appdelegate and I want that button navigate me to another ViewController. I already made a connection from my Storyboard, this connection is a type Modal Segue. I thought that performSegueWithIdentifier will do the job but it gives me the following error "has no segue with identifier 'showCamera' ". And I'm pretty sure that I have made that Identifier trough the Storyboard.

```
    let camera = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
     camera.addTarget(self, action: "takePicture:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside);

    //this function works 
    func takePicture(sender: UIButton!){
        println("Open Camera")

    //this throws an error        

self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("showCamera", sender: self) 
        }
```

Comment: Why init from AppDelegate?

Comment: What do you suggest? @Dato'MohammadNurdin

I have made a custom Button in my UITabbar so i can call the UIPickerController cautiously. I've to make that button in the appdelegate because my tabbar is initialized there.  If you have any other suggestion that would be more then welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add any view components in appDelegate. Just set UIViewController as rootViewController of window. Then add buttons to the UIViewController.Like this,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 

{
     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
   UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

In ViewController.m add your required UI components.

Comment: I'm working in Swift the example you provided is in Objective C. Swift doesnt have Implementation files.